# How to select value from MongoJS query output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I have MongoJS query call:

```
db.users.find({username:"eleeist"},function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

The `docs` variable looks like this in console output:

```
[ { _id: 4fee05662b17f88abbeb60b6,
    username: 'eleeist',
    password: 'test' } ]
```

I would like to display the password of the user `eleeist`.

I tried `docs.password` but get awful errors.

So how do I select values from the returned query result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docs` is an array of documents, so to get the password of the first one you'd use `docs[0].password`.